# Material Design Angular md-autocomplete remote

Tags: angularjs, material-design

In material design autocomplete(https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete)
All examples show how to get data from local variable.
There is no help on doing auto complete via AJAX call.

Comment: It does not matter where you get the data from. Post your code

Comment: Hello sajeetharan,
The example is here in source 
https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete
I just need a mechanism to make it a remote call rather than looking in  the local variable.

Comment: Just make an $http call and get the data

Comment: Yes! i am doing the $http but it is asynchronous i need to return something from the called function.
The function return as per the example is an expected array.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You just need to use a function that returns a promise in `md-items`. See this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/KFQg53ZVfPAMum0dFctK?p=preview

**NOTE**: Returned promises from `$http` will be resolved with an object that **has** the data. So you have to do something like this:

```
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
         return response.data.someOtherPathMaybe; // usually response.data
    })
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running..the preview in plunk

Comment: @aniltilanthe fixed it

Comment: could you implement the same on https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/demo/chips and provide a plunker for the same that would be really great help !