# How to show results from remote query in Angular-material autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm writing a website using [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) in which I use the [auto-complete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete). Within this autocomplete ([codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXMNMd)) there is a function which returns the searchresults from a local array of demo search-items which (simplified) looks like this:

```
function querySearch (query) {
    var results = query ? self.repos.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.repos, deferred;
    return results;
}
```

I now want to edit this code so that I can query the server after typing each letter. So I wrote the angular code to query the server and return a promise, [as instructed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29591052/4684732):

```
function querySearch (query) {
    return $http.get('/ajax/user/search/' + query).then(function(data){
        console.log(data); // I've got the data here. All fine.
        return data.data;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't really work; the server gets queried fine, but I see an empty list of suggestions as you can see below:

[image]

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Sorry - do you mean have it requery for the auto complete answers each time you type a letter?

Comment: @ajmajmajma - Yes indeed

Comment: The example does that - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete , check off simulate query, and disable cache

Comment: @ajmajmajma - I see the code with the $q and the timeout, but I wouldn't know how to edit that so that I can call my endpoint with it. Any tips would really help me out here.. :-)

Comment: Do you mean the querySearch function in that example? It just sets up a promise, so you'd pretty much replace the $timeout with the actual call. The point of this being I think what you want is already built in :)

Comment: @ajmajmajma - Yes, awesome! You made me look at it another time, and thanks to you tip I finally fixed it! If you add your suggestion as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help, angular material is awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the example here and click off simulate query and disable caching of queries  - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete

Just make sure you disable cache  `md-no-cache="false"` if you truly want it to fire every time and set `md-min-length="0"`

You just want to replace the timeout they have to mock the query with your actual query

```
function querySearch (query) {
  var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
      deferred;
  if (self.simulateQuery) {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    //repalce this
    $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
    return deferred.promise;
  } else {
    return results;
  }
}
```

And return your promise accordingly.

Comment: @Bergi aye, yeah, good catch. I was just copying the code from their examples.

Answer (score 0):

One quickfix would be to just return the function as:

```
function querySearch (query) {
    return $http.get('/ajax/user/search/' + query).success(function(data){
        console.log(data); // I've got the data here. All fine.
        return data.data;
    });
}
```

and then in the view change the call to:

```
md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)()"
```

therefore executing the function you return now.

(Codepen to showcase the solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdyEBy)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null` when typing. I tried removing the `()` at the end of the `md-items` line, but that leaves me with the same result: an empty list. Any more ideas?

Comment: That's a long shot but do you really want to return `data.data` and not just `data`?