# Angular material autocomplete with typehead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, typehead

Is there any way that I can implement autocomplete suggestions in material autocomplete angular js with typehead?
example:
Animals: Lion ,Tiger Birds: Eagle,Dove 
Like one in jquery autocomplete, https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, implement that code you have as a directive and work done. You may try with other directives like github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Answer (score 0):

Angular material has its own autocomplete directive. You can find it [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do via custom directive. Refer this link

[Material Design Angular md-autocomplete remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512238/material-design-angular-md-autocomplete-remote)

And this link [Angularjs autocomplete from $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460374/angularjs-autocomplete-from-http)